# Cropped Image Smarty 3.x

Tags: php, image, smarty, crop, smarty3

anyone know any plugin that can crop images using plugin smarty 3.x?
I found this plugin: http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/image-resizing-smarty#comment-12326
I think he's in trouble in version 3.x smarty because the following error message appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught -> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "file: .. \ santaideiapropaganda \ smarty \ templates \ news \
>   news-list.tpl" on line 9 "{imagesize src = $ item.imagem [width = 300
>   ]} "- Unexpected" = "I expected one of:" "," ","] "<- thrown
>   inC:\xampp\htdocs\sitepadrao\wp-content\themes\santaideiapropaganda\smarty\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php
>   on line 9

Can anybody help me? Maybe adptar the function.imagesize.php plugin version 3.x Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That error it's not a plugin fault, it's just that you're using it wrong. You know, when in a documentation about a function you see something like "[width=200]", the brackets mean that the parameter is optional, but you shouldn't write them; if wou need to use the parameter the correct way would be:

> {imagesize src=$imageUrl width=200}

Comment: When used like this:
`{Imagesize src = $ imageUrl width = 200}`

It appears the following error message:
`Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference Has Been removed in C: \ ... \ santaideiapropaganda \ smarty \ libs \ plugins \ function.imagesize.php on line 530`

Comment: That means that the plugin is outdated and doesn't work with the php version you're using. Look for a newer version or try to manually edit the plugin's php code removing the calls by reference where needed

Comment: Fix the issue of PHP version. But now the problem is that the "_supers" was removed from the 2.6 version of smarty and found smarty documentation to replace the current version